# Installing SSL cert on Amazon EC2 ELB

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I'm new to Amazon Web Services and have been trying to install a SSL certificate on the EC2 instance. I tried following AWS documentation, but found it baffling. I then followed the guide at http://www.robertbrewitz.com/2014/09/aws-and-setting-up-a-custom-ssl-certificate/.

I bought my SSL cert with Go Daddy, and generated 2 files using openssl:

```
server.key
server.csr
```

The guide said I should expect 3 certificates:

```
DigiCertCA.crt
TrustedRoot.crt
star_yourdomain_com.crt
```

Instead, I confusingly received 2 files named:

```
f6f65901b1708ae5.crt
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

I assume `f6f65901b1708ae5.crt` is my domain cert (but I'm not certain).  Anyway, the guide says I need an Elastic Load Balancer in order to install an SSL cert so I created one.

I generated the private key with:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -text
```

and the public key certficate with:

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in f6f65901b1708ae5.crt
```

I was also required to enter a Certificate Chain. I wasn't sure what this was and how to get it, so I guessed the command:

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

and entered the resulting certificate key that began with “-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----”

The guide continues, saying I then need to set up Cloudfront. I installed the aws command line tool and in order to generate the PEMs I ran:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -text > aws_private.pem
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in f6f65901b1708ae5.crt > aws_public.pem
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > aws_public.pem
```

I uploaded the SSL cert with:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name mydomain_com \
--certificate-body file://aws_public.pem --private-key file://aws_private.pem \
--certificate-chain file://aws_chain.pem --path /cloudfront/mydomain_com/
```

This was successful.

I then had to create a Cloudfront distribution, which I did, choosing the SSL cert.

However when I go to my https url (https://www.example.org/), it's not working. http://www.example.org/ however does work.

As there are an extraordinarily large amount of steps just for installing an SSL cert, I suspect I've made a mistake along the way. The problem is, I don't know where. Has anybody any pointers?

Also, are there not any simpler ways for installing an SSL cert? It seems to be ridiculously complex for something so common. I'd be willing to pay an expert to do it for me (I'm a software developer with almost no knowledge of anything SSL related), but its difficult to find anyone for such a task (and there is the problem of having to hand over login details etc). Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The suggestion below is that I should use [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/). I've had a look and this seems like a far more painless option. However, I did spend 86 euro on an SSL cert from Go Daddy so I'd prefer if that didn't go to waste. Is any of my work salvageable? Are there mean to resell SSL certs?

**EDIT**

I still haven't found a real solution to this. To clarify, I have a very niche site that will have very few visitors. I have the site on a EC2 instance. I followed the site above which advised using a Load Balancer and Cloudfront in order to encrypt with SSL. However, it's not working and it's probably overkill anyway. Can anyone help me with this? I'd like to use the SSL cert I paid for, but if not, should I use something like Lets Encrypt?

Comment: You installed the cert on CloudFront, not your EC2 instance. Are you using CloudFront as a CDN in front of your EC2 instance? You could have used the new AWS Certificate Manager to get a free certificate, very easily: https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Comment: I hadn't planned to use Cloudfront, i only used it because i was following the guide. Can i use my go daddy cert with the AWS certficate manager?

Comment: ive had a look at the Certificate Manager, it seems very straight forward. But ive already bought an SSL cert from Go Daddy:(

Comment: see: [sunk costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_costs)

Comment: @MarkB actually it looks like this is only available in Eastern United States region

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using your current SSL cert. That capability hasn't been removed or anything. You just complained that the process was complicated and asked if there was an easier way, so I suggested using ACM. Another easy option is to just use CloudFlare instead of CloudFront which will give you a free SSL certificate and a bunch of other features.

Comment: Also, you never answered my question regarding putting CloudFront in front of your EC2 server. Unless I'm missing it, I don't see that step in the tutorial you linked. I also wouldn't recommend using a tutorial that is two years old, things change quickly in cloud computing services and that sort of information can get outdated very quickly.

Comment: Yes, and i appreciate your help. Yes, im using Cloudfront in front of EC2 instance. There's a line in the tutorial saying "Edit your distribution or create a new one over at the CloudFront Dashboard." So I created a cloudfront distribution. Im onnly using Cloudfront because  it seems to be necessary when installing an SSL. My site is very niche, there wont be much traffic. Is cloudfront necessary?

Comment: What operating system are you using for your EC2 instance, make and version please.

Comment: I did cat /etc/os-release and result is: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned the guide saying to expect 3 files, including a "DigiCertCA.crt" file; sounds like it was written with DigiCert as your cert provider in mind, rather than GoDaddy.

### Certificates

First, to make sure that that "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" contains your requested certificate (and lay to rest any doubts there).  To do this, you can compare the data (*e.g.* Common Name (CN), DNS Subject Alternative Names (SANs), etc) in your "server.csr" file (that's the Certificate Signing Request) with what's in that "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" file:

```
$ openssl req -noout -text < server.csr
```

This should display human-readable text about the details for your domain in the CSR file.  Compare that with:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text < f6f65901b1708ae5.crt
```

This should display similar human-readable text, with more details/fields filled in.  But they should roughly have what you expect.  **Note** that if you see an error similar to this:

```
51299:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Then it suggests that your "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" file is in DER format, not PEM format.  If not, then you already have a PEM file, which is what AWS ELBs expect.  If you have a DER formatted cert, it's easy to convert to PEM format, using:

```
$ openssl x509 -in f6f65901b1708ae5.crt -inform DER -out f6f65901b1708ae5.pem -outform PEM
```

I just wanting to be thorough by mentioning this part.

Assuming, now, that we **know** that that "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" contains the PEM formatted certificate for your domain, we're ready to handle the "certificate chain" part.

I looked at GoDaddy's [online certificate repository](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository), to see if the "gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt" file you mentioned was there, and it was.  (It's OK for these files to be publicly available, as they contain the public certificates which are meant for anyone/everyone to use.)  Looking at that [gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt) file, I found that it contains *multiple* certificates.  This is important.

See, a "certificate chain" is a list of files which provide a *trust path* (or "chain"), from that "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" certificate you have to the trusted root GoDaddy CA certificate.  Each certificate has a *subject* (who it was issued *to*), and an *issuer* (who issued it).  This means that you can walk "backward", from your certificate to the issuer's certificate, to that certificate's issuer's certificate, *etc*.  This walking backward is the "certificate chain".

The fact that that "gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt" file contains multiple certificates implies that that file contains the certificate chain you need.  It also means that you do **not** want to do this:

```
$ openssl x509 -inform PEM -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > aws_public.pem
```

because `openssl x509` only reads the *first* certificate in the specified file, and you need *all* of them.

Given all of the above, you might need only the following (to make sure that your private key is PEM formatted):

```
$ openssl rsa -in server.key -text > aws_private.pem
```

And then, since we'll assume that "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" is already PEM formatted (and if not, you know how to convert it above), and we **know** that "gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt" is already PEM formatted, we'll now be ready to upload these to the AWS ELB.

### AWS ELB

To upload the certificates and key for use by the ELB, use something like this:

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate \
  --server-certificate-name redmatterapp_com2 \
  --certificate-body file://f6f65901b1708ae5.crt \
  --private-key file://aws_private.pem \
  --certificate-chain file://gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt \
  --path /cloudfront/redmatterapp_com/
```

*Note* that I used a different `--server-certificate-name`, just to make sure it didn't override/conflict with your existing configuration.  As a suggestion, you might include the date of when the cert being uploaded was created (or, better, when it will *expire*), as part of the name, as a hint to your future self of when that cert was added, *e.g.* "redmatterapp_com-2016-02-18".

Also **note** that if you are **not** using CloudFront, then you should **not** use the `--path` option.  If you *were* using CloudFront and then removed it, I'd highly recommend doing the above `aws iam upload-server-certificate` command again, only with a different `--server-certificate-name` and no `--path` option (and removing the previous name).  This may mean re-configuring any existing ELB HTTPS listeners to use the new certificate name, but it may be necessary, as that `--path` affects SSL handling.

Once the above is done, using the *e.g.* AWS Console, you should be able to configure your AWS ELB, and under the "Listeners" tab, click "Edit".  Add a Listener *e.g.* for "https".  When adding any SSL-capable listener, you'll see a "Change" link appear under the "SSL Certificate" column/tab.  Click that "Change", and choose the "existing certificate" button.  Under the "Certificate Name" dropdown, then, you should see an entry for the `--server-certificate-name` string/label you used above.  Choose that entry, then click "Save".  Now connections to that Listener, on your AWS ELB, should be properly configured for SSL/TLS connections that browsers will trust.

Thus the HTTPS Listener configuration would look something like:

- Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS
- Load Balancer Port: 443
- Instance Protocol: HTTP
- Instance Port: 80
- Cipher: (default policy)
- SSL Certificate: (`--server-certificate-name` name)

Note that you do *not* want to use port 443 for the instance port as well; if you do, that says that you want HTTPS *from the ELB to your instance*, which is not *usually* needed.  (Some secure sites want this, but that's a different topic/store.)  Thus the above configures the ELB to handle the SSL termination; to your Node.js server on the instance, it only ever receives plain HTTP requests on port 80:

```
client ---> HTTP ---> ELB port 80 ---> HTTP ---> server port 80
client ---> HTTPS --> ELB port 443 --> HTTP ---> server port 80
```

If your server needs to know whether the original request was HTTP or HTTPS, look for the `X-Forwarded-For` (and other request headers) that the AWS ELB will [automatically add to the request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html).

Now, once you have the ELB configured, it's a good step to verify that it's working properly.  First, you can use `openssl s_client` to verify that the SSL handshake works:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=redmatterapp.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=example.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4929 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    ...
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The above shows that we successfully completed an SSL handshake, and you can see that it shows the cert chain with the GoDaddy names; the "Server certificate" section should match the "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" PEM file you loaded.

### HTTPS and DNS

Now to test the *HTTPS* part; for this, I like to use `curl`, like so:

```
$ curl -kv https://example.com/
```

The `-v` option display more information, in particular whether the certificate matches the DNS name or not; the `-k` tells `curl` to ignore any certificate mismatches/issues, so that we can then see the verbose information about things.

This is where a little more configuration is necessary.  **If** you use the auto-generated ELB DNS name in your `curl` command (or in your browser), then you will most likely see security warnings/issues.  Why?  Because part of HTTPS is verifying that the DNS name you use in your URL *matches* the domain/host name in your server certificate, either as the Common Name (CN) in your certificate, *or* as one of the DNS Subject Alternative Names (SANs).  And you probably didn't include the ELB DNS name in your Certificate Signing Request (CSR) to GoDaddy.

This means, then, that the next step is to configure a DNS CNAME record that points to the AWS ELB name, e.g.:

```
www.example.com CNAME to aws-elb-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

If you're using AWS for DNS, then you could do this using *e.g.* Route 53.  Then you retry your `curl` command (or browser):

```
curl -kv https://www.example.com/
```

Another important thing to watch for (and you can see this in the `curl -v` output) is the contents of the `Host` request header.  Some HTTP servers (*i.e.* the one running on your backend instance) are very picky about the value there; they want the `Host` header to match something in their configuration, and if it doesn't, they may refuse the request.

Another common gotcha is:

- HTTP 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

If you get this response from your ELB, it *usually* means that your backend servers are not responding or are failing to respond to the ELB healtcheck.  Double-check that the port and path/URL used for the ELB healtcheck are correct, **and** that any firewalls or AWS Security Groups allow connectivity from the ELB to your instances.

So, now you should have an ELB which forwards port 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS) to your backend instances.  And you have a CNAME record for "www.example.com" in DNS that points to that ELB name.  What's left?

### HTTP Redirects

I **highly** recommend configuring your HTTP server to **always** redirect to the HTTPS equivalent of the same URL.  Why?

For security of the data between your clients and your server, using SSL/TLS is now expected.  So much so that more and more browsers automatically try HTTPS first, and only begrudgingly use HTTP as a fallback.  Browsers like Chrome (and others) want to avoid this HTTP fallback so much so that they've introduced mechanisms like [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security): a way for your site to tell the browser to *only ever use HTTPS for the site, never HTTP*.  Plus it's always a better marketing story; in fact, you can expect to get negative reactions from your clients/users if you **don't** use HTTPS.

There's another thing that using HTTPS for all your site's traffic protects you from: someone else using their DNS name and your ELB.  You have a CNAME record for "www.example.com" that points to "aws-elb-1.elb.amazonaws.com".  But what if I *also* create my own CNAME for "www.evilco.com", which points to the same "aws-elb-1.elb.amazonaws.com"?  Folks going to "www.evilco.com" will see **your** site, and think it's mine!

By forcing all traffic for your site to be HTTPS, you force all of the HTTPS clients to *verify* that the certificate presented by the server (*i.e.* your "f6f65901b1708ae5.crt" file) contains a Common Name (CN) or DNS Subject Alternative Name (SAN) that *matches* the domain name the client used in its URL.  Obviously your certificate does **not** contain CN or DNS SANs for "www.evilco.com", and thus that verification process would fail -- and the end user would see that something is fishy.  But if you allow HTTP traffic as well for your site, this phenomenon could happen -- and you, looking at your site's logs, would never know!

#### Postscript

I've not used the AWS Certificate Manager, or CloudFront, myself (so I can't comment on them), but I *have* used the above process, multiple times, for various certificate provisioning of multiple domains, at multiple jobs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your extremely thorough answer. I tried all this, but still https is not working. I also deleted the cloudfront distribution as looks like I dont need it. f6f65901b1708ae5.crt was in PEM format and when i ran command above, i saw that it was for my domain. My node app is listening on port 8080. I already have an iptables rule forwarding traffic from port 80 to port 8080. That works for http traffic. I added another rule to forward traffic to 443 to 8080. However, https is still not working...

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? What ports (frontend, backend/instance) your ELB HTTPS listener using? Is there a DNS name/IP address for ELB hat I could test myself, so I can help more?

Comment: I've updated my post with debugging/testing steps, and added a part about some necessary DNS CNAME configuration.

Comment: Currently "www.redmatterapp.com" resolves to an IP address (52.36.104.235), which is for "ec2-52-36-104-235.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"; how long should I wait for your DNS records to update, to pick up the CNAME change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104052/discussion-between-castaglia-and-mark).