# Misconfiguration of SSL Certificate for AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I am attempting to configure a SSL certificate to support HTTPS through an AWS ELB. I have everything configured:

1) GoDaddy SSL cert configured within AWS ELB (including the certificate chain).
2) Have the ELB listeners looking like this:
   client ---> HTTPS --> ELB port 443 --> HTTP ---> server port 80
3) Within GoDaddy, created a CNAME entry such as this:
   service.acme.com CNAME to aws-some-region.elb.amazonaws.com
4) If I curl -kv https://service.acme.com/

```
*   Trying 52.6.xxx.xx...
* Connected to service.acme.com (52.6.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: pixxeen.com
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: service.acme.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 14:06:08 GMT 
< ETag: W/"154-1455797592000"
< Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 12:13:12 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 154
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acme Service Application</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor=white>
      <p>Acme Service Application</p>
  </body>
* Connection #0 to host service.acme.com left intact
```

The HTML is an index.html page that I have deployed for the ELB to request to confirm the EC2 instance is up and running.

However, the problem I am running into is if any mobile client framework hits the service.acme.com service endpoints (okhttp or AFNetworking), I am seeing the following (this is an okhttp call):

```
02-22 08:52:10.513 2564-2564/com.acme W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname service.acme.com not verified:
02-22 08:52:10.513 2564-2564/com.acme W/System.err:     certificate: sha1/+axZF3Oyaatuoio5rsmNhUUhOZE=
02-22 08:52:10.513 2564-2564/com.acme W/System.err:     DN: CN=acme.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
02-22 08:52:10.513 2564-2564/com.acme W/System.err:     subjectAltNames: [acme.com, www.acme.com]
```

So, does anyone have an idea where I went wrong?

I paddled around StackOverflow and ran into this post (one of the most detailed I have seen): [Installing SSL cert on Amazon EC2 ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468996/installing-ssl-cert-on-amazon-ec2) and it seems to confirm all of the steps I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate is not valid for the ***service.acme.com*** domain name.

It's only valid for the exact hosts ***acme.com*** and ***www.acme.com***.

You will see this error clearly if you omit the `-k` (insecure) option of `curl` (which is not a good test flag since it intentionally ignores most SSL problems)

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, it is because I did not purchase a certificate that allowed subdomains, correct?  So, my only choice is to redo the CNAME like this: acme.com CNAME to aws-some-region.elb.amazonaws.com which is not something I like because I really did not want the top-level domain pointing at the AWS ELB.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra Either that or go for a separate cert for the service endpoint. They're not excessively expensive nowadays and may be worth it to not have to mix web and services.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate attached to the ELB will be validated against the cname not the ELB name itself. If you have attached the certificate x.y.z.com to the ELB , than you cname should match x.y.z.com and not the ELB cname.

If you have the wild card cert *.x.y.z.com , than your cname can be anything.x.y.z.com to be compliant.